# Can we cache images in flutter without using database?

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I have been working on an e-commerce app. As there are a lot of images to be loaded for product listing I tried to cache the images using flutter_advanced_networkimage: ^0.7.0, and cached_network_image 2.5.0  packages. It seems that images are cached and loaded only if the app is in memory.

ie: if the os kills the app or user closes the app from the background the cached data lost.

Is there any better way to cache images for use-cases like e-commerce?

Thanks.

Comment: Are fetching images from Firebase ?

Comment: No. I have python backend. I need some way to cache the images and to load from the device if an image with the same URL comes up again.

Comment: `cached_network_image` saving images to cache directory of an application. On Android, images saved in app directory in `cache` folder.

Comment: I asked about Firebase because they have this issue of changing the url (token changes) even if the image is the same and this is considered as new image for the library, so in your case probably the images is not just downloaded due to you internet speed maybe ? give it sometime open and check again ?

Comment: if you just need to cache some data then consider using https://pub.dev/packages/hive it's a package which allows you to cache data. The cached data will not be lost even if the os terminates the app. It will only be removed if you manually do it in by going to app's settings.